# vb.net Naming a button from Database

Tags: vb.net

I need some assistance in generate buttons/tiles based on a database vales for example if have 5 people in the database it will create 5 buttons on the form, so on load it will connect to the data base and name the 5 buttons based on the first name of the user.

i know i am missing something but not too sure what here is what i have so far any help would be great

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader


Public Class Main

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nate\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet11.StudentTB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StudentTBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet11.StudentTB)

        cmd.Connection = cn
        Dim Ps As Integer
        Dim nm As String
        Ps = StudentTBBindingSource.Count
        nm = "select * from StudentTB"

        Dim I As Integer

        For I = 1 To Ps

            Dim srt As New Button
            srt.Width = 50
            srt.Height = 50
            srt.Text = nm
            srt.Visible = True
            srt.Location = New Point(I * 30, 0)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(srt)

        Next

    End Sub
```

i added this coded it seem to try to work but then i came up saying their is no value in position 1

```
srt.Text = Database1DataSet11.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("FirstName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Array index start at zero and ends at Count - 1

```
For I = 0 To Ps - 1
```

should fix your problem on the row access, but then you need

```
srt.Location = New Point((I+1) * 30, 0)
```

Comment: how do i get the buttons to go on to the next line dynamically ?

Comment: At which point? After the first 3, 2 or each on a separate line?

Comment: after it fills the window horizontally it just seems to draw the button on the same line, what i want it to do is when i get to the edge of the window size go to the next line. hope that makes sense